# EMPTY RECORD in table DATABASE SERVER sending data using cURL

Tags: php, curl

I have tried sending some data from database local to database server.
The name of table in database local is “inbox”.
 The data in “inbox” I transform to XML 
This is for the code (`inboek2.php`) this script in local pc

```
<?php
mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysql_select_db('sms');

header('Content-Type: text/xml');
echo "&lt;?xml version='1.0'?&gt;";

echo "<inbox>";

$query = "SELECT  inbox.id, ReceivingDateTime, SenderNumber, TextDecoded FROM inbox ORDER BY inbox.id";
$hasil = mysql_query($query);
while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($hasil))
{
   // representasi data sms
   echo "<data>";
   echo "<id>".$data['id']."</id>";
   echo "<tgl>".$data['ReceivingDateTime']."</tgl>";
   echo "<nope>".$data['SenderNumber']."</nope>";
   echo "<isi>".$data['TextDecoded']."</isi>";
   echo "</data>";
}
echo "</inbox>";
?>
```

The result of script `inboek2.php`, it will be catch by script `proses.php`

This is for code `proses.php` ( this script in local pc ) :

```
 <?php
    // koneksi ke mysql di server localhost
    mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
    mysql_select_db('sms');

    // baca data XML dari script inboek2.php yang digenerate oleh data.php
    $dataxml = simplexml_load_file&#40;'http://localhost/baca/inboek2.php'&#41;;
    foreach($dataxml->data as $data)
    {

       $id = $data->id;
       $tgl = $data->tgl;
       $nope = $data->nope;
       $isi = $data->isi;

       $curlHandle = curl_init();
       $curResponse = curl_exec&#40;$curlHandle&#41;;
       curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.adibiken.com/SEM/kir.php');
       curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'id='.$id.'&amp;tgl='.$tgl.'&amp;nope='.$nope.'&amp;isi='.$isi);
       //and if i delete another variable atleast still the last one variable the data has been sucessfull sending whitout empty record ,,this is weird,,,,,
       curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
       curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
       curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,30);
       curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
       curl_exec&#40;$curlHandle&#41;;
       curl_close($curlHandle);
       echo $curResponse;
    }
    ?>
```

and the last one, this is code for `kir.php` in HOSTING

```
<?php
include "koneksi.php";

$id = $_POST['id'];
$tgl = $_POST['tgl'];
$isi = $_POST['isi'];
$nope = $_POST['nope'];

// query insert data ke mysql
$quer = "INSERT INTO `adibiken_sem`.`inbox` (`id`,`tgl` ,`isi` ,`nope`) VALUES ( '".$id."','".$tgl."', '".$isi."', '".$nope."')";
mysql_query($quer);
?>
```

**PROBELM : what should i do, to make the  variable : `$id , $tgl, $isi, $nope`are have been SUCCESFULL SENDING to database WITHOUT EMPTY RECORD ???**

and if i delete another variable atleast still the last one variable the data has been sucessfull sending whitout empty record ,,
this is weird,,,,,

Answer (score 0):

you can check that with:

```
if(isset($_POST['id'])){
    $id = $_POST['id']; 
}else{
    //the POST variable was empty, do something.
}
```

Comment: oh, it's in `kir.php`, it's a way to check if the values this script receives are set or not. If any of the conditionals fail you should not execute the INSERT, thus avoiding the empty values in the database.

Comment: dear mr naryl. i allready check that, 

`<?php include "koneksi.php";
if(isset($_POST['id'])==0;($_POST['tgl'])==0;($_POST['isi'])==0;($_POST['nope'])==0;)

{
    echo "data kosong"; 
}else{
    $quer = "INSERT INTO `adibiken_sem`.`inbox` (`id`,`tgl` ,`isi` ,`nope`) VALUES ( '".$id."','".$tgl."', '".$isi."', '".$nope."')";
mysql_query($quer);
}
 
?>`

the data are not save mr, any ideas?

Comment: mr, if i delete another variable atleast still the last one variable the data have been sucessfull sending whitout empty record mr,,
this is weird,,,,,

Answer (score 0):

You could try check the length of each variable to make sure they aren't empty before inserting. This can be done with either strlen or mb_strlen.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php

Comment: dear mr.Frd, i already check that, but the all setting the length of variable in table are same,,what else mr??

Comment: mr, if i delete another variable atleast still the last one variable the data have been sucessfull sending whitout empty record mr,,
this is weird,,,,,